# My array doesn't seem to work in methods outside the main?

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, for-loop, methods

http://pastebin.com/98q57mzj

This has to do with a textbox array and an int array. Somehow, the values of the arrays seem to work within the main method, but not in other methods.

So from lines 34 to 44, I assign values to my arrays in the main, and then from lines 48 to 56 I use a for loop to make it so only certain keys are allowed when typing in the textboxes. Then in another method from lines 64 to 70, I try to use another for loop to make a "" string value equal to 0, or otherwise grab the value within the textbox and set that value to the variables within the numbers[] array. This doesn't seem to work. Changing the values in the textboxes doesn't seem to change the values of the numbers[] array. However, it does work if I type it out, as I did from lines 71 to 94. I don't want to take the easy way out and just type it out, I want to know why this loop isn't working so I can learn more about arrays and methods and so I'd know how to fix similar issues in the future.

For convenience:

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        inputs[0] = textBox1;
        inputs[1] = textBox2;
        inputs[2] = textBox3;
        inputs[3] = textBox4;
        inputs[4] = textBox5;

        numbers[0] = oneYear;
        numbers[1] = twoYear;
        numbers[2] = threeYear;
        numbers[3] = fourYear;
        numbers[4] = moreYear;

        textBox6.ReadOnly = true;

        for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
        {
            inputs[i].KeyDown += (obj, args) =>
            {
                Keys[] allowedKeys = { Keys.Back, Keys.Next, Keys.Delete, Keys.Left, Keys.Right };
                args.SuppressKeyPress = !allowedKeys.Contains(args.KeyCode) && (args.KeyValue < 48 || args.KeyValue > 57);
            };
            inputs[i].Text = 0.ToString();
        }
    }

    private void autobots()
    {
        try
        {
             //find out why this doesn't work
            for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
            {
                if (inputs[i].Text == "")
                    numbers[i] = 0;
                else
                    numbers[i] = Convert.ToInt32(inputs[i].Text);
            }
            /*if (textBox1.Text == "")
                oneYear = 0;
            else
                oneYear = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);

            if (textBox2.Text == "")
                twoYear = 0;
            else
                twoYear = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);

            if (textBox3.Text == "")
                threeYear = 0;
            else
                threeYear = Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text);

            if (textBox4.Text == "")
                fourYear = 0;
            else
                fourYear = Convert.ToInt32(textBox4.Text);

            if (textBox5.Text == "")
                moreYear = 0;
            else
                moreYear = Convert.ToInt32(textBox5.Text);*/

            oneTotal = oneYear * 24;
            twoTotal = twoYear * 27;
            threeTotal = threeYear * 30;
            fourTotal = fourYear * 33;
            moreTotal = moreYear * 36;

            total = oneTotal + twoTotal + threeTotal + fourTotal + moreTotal;
            textBox6.Text = total.ToString();
            //label6.Text = ("$") + total.ToString();
        }
        catch
        {
            textBox6.Text = "";
            //label6.Text = "";
        }
    }
```

Comment: How are you checking if the numbers array is changed? If you are looking at the oneYear, etc, variables: these would hold their own values, and do point to the same storage of the value as the values inside the numbers array.

Comment: We don't have your linenumbers, that makes this a big puzzle. Try to replicate the problem in a smal (10-20 line) Console app.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Had your initial reaction of the linenumbers as well, but they are included in the pastebin of the link on top. Besides that, about the puzzling part, I have a sneaking supsicion that this is a misunderstanding in how structs are stored.

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop is working correctly....However, in order to shed some light on why this isn't working the way you need it to:

```
 numbers[0] = oneYear;
 numbers[1] = twoYear;
 numbers[2] = threeYear;
 numbers[3] = fourYear;
 numbers[4] = moreYear;
```

When you do this you are storing the value of the variables into the array...not the variables themselves.

```
    for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
    {
         if (inputs[i].Text == "" || inputs[i] == null)
               numbers[i] = 0;
         else
```

**here you set the value in the i position of the numbers array. to the value of                  whats in the text box. This does not change the value of your variables ("oneYear", "twoYear", etc..)**

```
         numbers[i] = Convert.ToInt32(inputs[i].Text);
    }
```

**but here you are are using the variables (ie "oneYear", "twoYear") which have not
had a new value stored in them. Remember the numbers[] array does not directly effect these  variables
the numbers[] array (because it is an array of type int) only stored the values of these variables not a reference to the variables themselves. Because of this the code here does not do what you want it to.**

```
    oneTotal = oneYear * 24;
    twoTotal = twoYear * 27;
    threeTotal = threeYear * 30;
    fourTotal = fourYear * 33;
    moreTotal = moreYear * 36;

    total = oneTotal + twoTotal + threeTotal + fourTotal + moreTotal;
    textBox6.Text = total.ToString();
```

In order to get this code to work correctly you would need to use the values in the numbers[] array. Like this:

```
oneTotal = numbers[0] * 24;
twoTotal = numbers[1] * 27; 
threeTotal = numbers[2] * 30;
etc...
```

When you do this it will output the correct results to textBox6.

The first section of code I pasted is only useful if the oneYear, twoYear, threeYear, fourYear, moreYear variables have a non-zero default value or have a value set before it ever gets to this code, and because you are using the numbers[] array to store the values from the text box you will not see the calculations you want to see, unless you use the numbers[] array values. Or if  you're dead set on using the oneYear, twoYear... variables just use the if-else statments you have commented out, or put:

oneYear = numbers[0];
twoYear = numbers[1];
etc..

**A little more clarification:**

I think the reason you might have gotten a little confused here is because you are using two different types of arrays. A TextBox array used to store your textboxes, and an int array used to store the values in the text boxes. The TextBox array is storing objects...or a reference(pointer) to an object. So when you say inputs[0] = textBox1; you are telling the program to store the reference to textBox1 in the first element of the inputs[] array allowing you to directly manipulate the textBoxes stored in this array, but because the int type is a primary data type when it is stored in an array only its value is stored, not the variable itself.

Last thing: 
You would need to create/use a wrapper class for your int variables in order to do what you are trying to do the way you are trying to do it.